# how to extract part of a string in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I use `last | grep pts/` to check who login my raspberry Pi:

```
samuelli pts/2        localhost        Fri Apr 24 19:51   still logged in   
pi       pts/1        localhost        Fri Apr 24 19:50 - 19:53  (00:03)    
liuly    pts/1        localhost        Fri Apr 24 19:50 - 19:50  (00:00)
```

Now I want to extract the user name like `pi` and their login time like `Fri Apr 24 19:51` and output username and time into a file. How could I to write this script ?  Using `cut` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  The problem with `cut` is that it doesn't handle variable amounts of spaces well.  Check out `awk` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` will print out the username as well as time and the `>>` can redirect it to a text file:

`last | grep pts/ | awk '{print $1 " "$4 " "$5 " "$6 " "$7}' >> sampletest.txt`

Comment: One of the main features of an `awk` program is the condition that may precede the action block. It often makes sense to use that condition to select lines instead of an extra `grep`: `last | awk ' /pts\// {print [...]`